# Limit front-end file upload size in Magento

Tags: file-upload, magento-1.7, filesize

So here's my problem. My admins need to upload files that can be anywhere from 2-500 MB's each. I've set my php.ini settings appropriately and all is well with this requirement. But now I've been asked to allow guests to upload files from the front-end. Obviously, I do not want to give them the ability to upload 500 MB files.

I've searched around and have been unable to find a decent answer for allowing large file uploads in the admin while limiting front-end guests to smaller file sizes.

So how do you allow your admin's to continue uploading extremely large files while restricting front-end users to a smaller file sizes?

Here's my solution:

```
public function saveAction()
{
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    $helper = Mage::helper('my_module');
    if ( $post ) {
        try {
            if ($_FILES['size'] >= 2000000) { // Limit is set to 2 MB
                $errors[] = $helper->__('You have exceeded the max file size.');
                $error = true;
            }
            if ($error) {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            // Perform save operations here.
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            foreach($errors as $error) {
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($error);
            }
            $this->_redirect('*/*/*');
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

This checks to see if the file exceeds the limit. If it does, it throws an exception.

Anyway, I'm looking for better/alternative solutions to this same problem. Post them if you've got them!

Answer (score 0):

I can give you the basic idea on how you can achieve this. In your `saveAction()` of admin add this `Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId()` This will return the current website ID. The admin website ID will be always `0`. So add an IF condition in the `saveAction()` to check whether the current website ID is `0 or other`.

If the return value is not equal to `0` then you can limit the size to `50MB` or what ever u want. If it is equal to `0` then you can allow the limit upto `500MB`.

Hope this helps.